# Overlapping ROC curves in multi plot of ROC curves

Tags: r, roc, auc, proc-r-package

I am trying to make a ROC plot with multiple univariate models. But two of my variables are overlapping since their AUC were similar (0.74 and 0.739). I was wondering if there was a way I can separate these curves?

This is the code I used:

```
par(pty="s")
roc(na.exclude(DATA$Outcome), glmVari1$fitted.values, plot=TRUE, legacy.axes=FALSE, percent=TRUE, col="maroon1", lwd=2)
plot.roc(na.exclude(DATA$Outcome), glmVari2$fitted.values, percent=TRUE, col="cyan", lwd=2, print.auc=FALSE, add=TRUE)
plot.roc(na.exclude(DATA$Outcome), glmVari3$fitted.values, percent=TRUE, col="skyblue3", lwd=2, print.auc=FALSE, add=TRUE)
plot.roc(na.exclude(DATA$Outcome), glmVari4$fitted.values, percent=TRUE, col="seagreen4", lwd=2, print.auc=FALSE, add=TRUE)
plot.roc(na.exclude(DATA$Outcome), glmVari5$fitted.values, percent=TRUE, col="green", lwd=2, print.auc=FALSE, add=TRUE)
plot.roc(na.exclude(DATA$Outcome), glmVari6$fitted.values, percent=TRUE, col="orangered3", lwd=2, print.auc=FALSE, add=TRUE)
legend("bottomright", c("Variable 1", "Variable 2", "Varible 3 ", "Variable 4", "Variable 5", "Variable 6"), 
col = c("maroon1", "cyan", "skyblue3", "seagreen4", "green", "orangered3"), lwd=2, cex = 0.62)
```

Using this code, I get the following plot. In this, Variable 6 and 4 are overlapping since they have the same AUC (0.74 and 0.739 respectively). Can you please help me on how to separate them in the code itself?

[image]

Comment: You can't really separate the lines without changing their coordinates, which means they will no longer represent the true values of your ROC. Your options are to make one of the lines a dotted line, make the lines semi-transparent, or produce more than one plot.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make the line underneath wider with `lwd`

```
plot.roc(na.exclude(DATA$Outcome), glmVari4$fitted.values, percent=TRUE, col="seagreen4", lwd=4, print.auc=FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

Or you may want the curve on top of the other one to be dotted with `lty`

```
plot.roc(na.exclude(DATA$Outcome), glmVari6$fitted.values, percent=TRUE, col="orangered3", lwd=2, lty=3, print.auc=FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! thats what I ended up doing. Making one semi transparent and the other dashed.